# How do I add a print statement to count the number of lines with a keyword in linux

Tags: linux

Say I have the input file:
hello hello hello
hello hello hello
hello hello hello
hello hello hello
hello hello hello
b
dr
t
4
t

I want to be able to print out just the n lines containing hello and an additional line "found 'n' lines with hello"
I have already gotten started with using a grep command 'grep hello hello.txt'
and I know 'wc -l' finds how many lines that output has.
My idea is to pipe it somehow maybe using the sed tool although Im not too sure how to do so.

Comment: `grep 'hello' file; grep -c 'hello' file` **or**
`grep 'hello' file && grep -c 'hello' file`. (the second form makes the call for the count conditional on the success of finding `"hello"` in the file)

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score -1):

Use awk, not sed:

```
$ grep pattern file | awk '{ print } END { printf("Found %d matching lines\n", NR) }'
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it quite simply with a call to `grep` to math the lines containing `"hello`" and a second call to `grep -c` to get the count of the lines containing `"hello"`, e.g.

```
$ grep 'hello' file && grep -c 'hello' file
hello hello hello
hello hello hello
hello hello hello
hello hello hello
hello hello hello
5
```

By including `&&` between the commands, the call for the count of the number of times `"hello"` occurs is conditioned on there being `"hello"` in the file. If you want to output `"0"` if no match is found, then you can add and `|| echo '0'`, e.g.

```
$ grep 'hello' file && grep -c 'hello' file || echo '0'
```

Which will simply output `"0"` if `"hello"` is not contained in the file.

Comment: Downvoter, at least have the integrity to explain your downvote and leave a comment. Feel free to point out any technical inaccuracy in the answer (or any of the answers above -- since it appears you simply went down the line downvoting to satisfy some deep insecurity or feelings of inadequacy). Instead of being destructive, why not post your answer -- so we can all learn how it really should be done.

Answer (score -1):

You can write a one liner using awk 
 awk '/hello/' hello.txt | awk '{print} END{printf("found %d lines with hello"), NR}'